# Jar file Initializer exception

Tags: java, swing, exception, command-line, executable-jar

I have a Jar file which is composed of a lot of classes. When I run it from command line (rather tahn double clicking) I get this:
[image]

I saw that it happens if there is a problem in `static{}` blocks but `JPanelFactory` class has no static blocks. What could be causing it ?
**also**
it says there are 18 more errors. I can not view those. How can I view those?

### JPanelFactory

```
public class JPanelFactory {
    static JPanel holder = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,5,5));
    static JLabel addNewTaskLabel = new JLabel(constants.IconNames.addVideo,JLabel.CENTER);
    static JLabel deleteTaskLabel = new JLabel(constants.IconNames.deleteVideo,JLabel.CENTER);

    protected JPanelFactory(){

    }

    public static JPanelFactory newInstance(TransferHandler addHandler, TransferHandler removeHandler){
        addNewTaskLabel.setTransferHandler(addHandler);
        deleteTaskLabel.setTransferHandler(removeHandler);
        return new JPanelFactory();
    }

    public JPanel newJPanel(){
        holder.add(addNewTaskLabel);
        holder.add(deleteTaskLabel);
        return holder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Scroll down and read the inner exception.

Comment: @SLaks This is soo long that it shows `and 18 more..` if I scroll. There is no second exception shown. Yeah, `IconNames` has a `static{}` block

Comment: That means 18 more lines of stack trace.  Please paste the complete console output.

Comment: @SLaks HOW do I see the full stack trace ?

Comment: The full stack trace is not particularly important.   However, there should be more output below it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ExceptionInInitializerError` happening in a `<clinit>` means something in a `static { ... }` initializer block or the initializer expression of a `static` field threw an exception.  There should be a "caused by" further down the stack trace telling you what the underlying exception was.  I presume in this case it's one of the initializer expressions for the `static JPanel ...` fields that's at fault, the line number in the stack trace (`JPanelFactory.java:8`) should tell you which one.

The "18 more" is a shorthand which means that the remainder of the "caused by" stack trace is identical to the last 18 lines of the original trace (in this case of the `ExceptionInInitializerError`).  This can save a lot of space when printing the stack trace of a long chain of exceptions.